# Function logging not showing details in Kudu - Log param always appears null

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I am working through replacing some WebJobs with Azure Functions and appear to have all working OK except for logging of what is going on.
I have tried using the default function created within VS2017 and have run it locally with no problems.  When deployed to Azure I cannot see the detail of the log entries anywhere.

Using Kudu to view the logs seemed OK except that I noticed that the log param of a function invocation is always null.  This can't be the case as the function does run, and gives the expected output, and would fail if log was really null.

Here's what the function looks like:

```
public static class Function1
{
    [FunctionName("Function1")]
    public static async Task<IActionResult> Run(
        [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", "post", Route = null)] HttpRequest req,
        ILogger log)
    {
        log.LogInformation("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");

        string name = req.Query["name"];

        string requestBody = await new StreamReader(req.Body).ReadToEndAsync();
        dynamic data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(requestBody);
        name = name ?? data?.name;

        return name != null
            ? (ActionResult)new OkObjectResult($"Hello, {name}")
            : new BadRequestObjectResult("Please pass a name on the query string or in the request body");
    }
}
```

I would have expected to see the output of the log within Kudu by going to https://xxx.scm.azurewebsites.net/azurejobs/#/functions but I can't see the details when I toggle the output - it never loads (and it shows the log param as being null - perhaps is being resolved by DI though).

Whilst this function is simply a test I do have other more complicated functions that I need the logging details for.

I am not keen on investigating Application Insights as this seems way, way overkill for such simple functions that will not be used very heavily.

Comment: By `log param of a function invocation is always null`, do you mean there is no logs under `D:\home\LogFiles\Application\Functions\function\Function1` in kudu?

Comment: There are entries in that folder that do have the correct logging information in them.  I can't see this from within the Kudo portal when clicking the Toggle Output button. The log param is referring to the parameters passed to the function.  I understand that this is resolved from DI.

Comment: This is weird though as they were not there when I looked a couple of hours ago.  I was checking everywhere for some logs but none were to be found.

Comment: For Azure WebJobs Dashboard, I am afraid it has been deprecated for v2 functions, no logs are sent there as you have found.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For v2 functions in runtime 2.x, [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-versions#changes-in-features-and-functionality) explains

> the WebJobs dashboard in the portal, which used the [AzureWebJobsDashboard](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-app-settings#azurewebjobsdashboard) setting is replaced with Azure Application Insights, which uses the [APPINSIGHTS_INSTRUMENTATIONKEY](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-app-settings#appinsightsinstrumentationkey) setting.

Like what you have seen, with AzureWebJobsDashboard setting, the log param is null and no log there. I am afraid the **replaced with** was enforced and Dashboard has been deprecated.

As for the usage of Application insights, we could just leverage the basic log monitoring without any further investigation. After creating it and add its instrumentationkey in Application settings, we could see the Monitor view is similar to Dashboard.

[image]

If we don't like it anyway, logs in kudu(`https://<functionAppName>.scm.azurewebsites.net/DebugConsole`) are ready there(`D:\home\LogFiles\Application\Functions\function\<functoinName>`).

Comment: Thanks Jerry, looks like I will have to find out about another technology, application Insights, that I was trying to avoid.  Let's hope it's a good experience.